# SQL Server unexpectedly rolling back transaction

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, transactions, rollback

Using SQL Server 2016+ and VB.Net

I am currently seeing an issue where I have gaps in my logs.  These logs are created by manually inserting information into a log table to track things like creating sessions, adding items to baskets, changes to preferences, etc.

I can tell there are gaps as we have an identity field and there are missing lines.  I can simulate this with the following script.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempLog;

CREATE TABLE #TempLog (ID         INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
,                      TimeStamp  DATETIME
                           DEFAULT GETDATE()
,                      LogMessage NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #TempLog (LogMessage)
VALUES ('Message 1')
,      ('Message 2');

BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT INTO #TempLog (LogMessage)
VALUES ('Message 3')
,      ('Message 4');

ROLLBACK TRAN;

INSERT INTO #TempLog (LogMessage)
VALUES ('Message 5')
,      ('Message 6');

SELECT * FROM #TempLog

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempLog;
```

Output

```
ID          TimeStamp               LogMessage
----------- ----------------------- -----------------
1           2019-05-10 09:13:47.647 Message 1
2           2019-05-10 09:13:47.647 Message 2
5           2019-05-10 09:13:47.647 Message 5
6           2019-05-10 09:13:47.647 Message 6
```

From this you can tell that if the logs are created inside a transaction and that transaction is rolled back, the identity value is does not reset.

When I perform session setups directly through SSMS they always create correctly and without any gaps in the logs.  When we call the session setups through our "middle tier" package (VB.NET with a web front end) it usually works fine, but occasionally takes much longer (15-20 seconds instead of < 2 seconds) and I see a lot of gaps in the logs.

Please note this is the same stored procedure with the only difference being where it is called from.  There are no transaction as part of this process, and are used very sparingly usually only through our administration processes where large sweeping changes are implemented.  In these cases logs are created outside the transaction.

I'm wondering does .NET wrap calls inside its own version of a transaction thereby causing these rollbacks?  There may be some other underlying cause here, server load etc, however without being able to see whats in the logs I cannot track anything down. I have been advised by the developers that they "aren't doing anything in transactions" and they "aren't causing this".

Would a time out due to load cause this? Would a cancelled call do this? Unfortunately my .NET exposure is limited and I'm now at a bit of a loss.  Since this is an intermittent fault, stepping through the code has proved to be in-effective.

I could duplicate all the log creation to push to the SQL Server Logs via raise error, but I'd rather not flood the logs with informational messages, rather keep that for actual errors.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: What size are the gaps? Is it a round number like `1,000` or `10,000`?

Comment: 10 - 15 rows.  An average session setup contains about 60 rows of logs

Comment: This is on a development database with only the developers attached to it. I'd be expecting 1000's of consecutive sessions in real world situations.

Comment: Technically speaking there are no gaps in the logs. If other transactions had to wait to see if the auto-number was going to be used or "rolled back", they would be blocked by the existing transaction using the auto-number. 

The issue here is really the missing items issue. A time out will not cause this, to fully understand what is happening they need you to have a look at the source or they have to account for the discrepancies. 

For the developers: This is not an intermittent issue - this is a go-live blocker.

Comment: Time to start [tracing statement execution](https://www.brentozar.com/extended-events/) in your server to find the source of the problem in the code. For a lightly used dev environment, the profiler is an easy option.

Comment: Can you show the VB .Net code that saves the logs?